# Как убрать часть адреса из input?

Tags: html, input

Есть произвольных адрес в input1 (Россия, Московская область, Пушкино)

Необходимо вывести в input2 только то, что после последней запятой (Пушкино). Адреса разные, так что требуется какое-то уникальное для всех действие. Помогите пожалуйста в виде кода.

Comment: Всё ещё актуально.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var in_ = document.querySelector('#in');
var out_ = document.querySelector('#out');

in_.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var InValue = e.target.value;
  if (InValue.lastIndexOf(',') >= 0) {
    out_.value = InValue.substring(InValue.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in">
<input type="text" id="out">
```